# htaccess to nginx conversion reverse proxy to keep URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

i am using post affiliate pro and they have a script to turn a web page at www.example.com into a banner for affiliates, the htaccess uses a php script to load the affiliates info into the website/banner.

i am trying to convert the htaccess to nginx conf file. i have tried the converters at winginx and anilcetin 
they work but it changes the url from www.example to pap.example.

on an Apache server with .htaccess the url is maintained www.example. this is what i am trying to duplicate on the nginx server.

here is the htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*) http://pap.example.com/scripts/page.php?a_aid=$1&a_bid=7c4ec277&a_file=$2 [L,P,QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) http://pap.example.com/scripts/page.php?a_aid=$1&a_bid=7c4ec277&a_redir=Y [L,P,QSA]
```

thanks for any help

Sean

Comment: Can you give examples of how each URL will be changed in each condition.

Comment: the rewriting is to keep the affiliates ID in the url, as far as what the page.php does i am not completely sure as it is an encoded file. but basically if the affiliate sends a link with their ID such as www.example,com/seanc, as the visitor browses this special site the URL's would be re written as www.example,com/seanc/page1 www.example,com/seanc/page2 rather than pap.example,com/scripts/page.php?a_aid=seacn&a_bid=7c4ec277&a_file=page1.   this will explain what is actually supposed to happen http://support.qualityunit.com/307164-Site-Replication

Comment: the way i understand it is the first 2 conditions check to see if there is an actual directory or a file after the / so for example sitemap.xml wont be interpreted as an affiliate ID, then the rewrite line uses mod proxy to access page.php to look up the affiliates info and change the tags placed in the websites HTML to reflect the affiliates info.

the second instance of the conditional rules and page.php is to update the tracking info to credit the affiliate for future purchases.

Comment: i have had some success with this in the conf file but it does not proxy it redirects
`location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/(.*) / break;
    proxy_pass http://team.aspoonfulofhealth.com/scripts/page.php?a_aid=$1&a_bid=7c4ec277&a_file=$2;
  }
  }
location / {  
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^/]+) / break;
    proxy_pass http://team.aspoonfulofhealth.com/scripts/page.php?a_aid=$1&a_bid=7c4ec277&a_redir=Y;
  }
}`